# Updating data in UITableView after asynchronous load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm loading some data from a web service that I want use in a `UITableView`. I can set some initial values for the `UITableView`. However if I update those details the `completionHandler` block, the update doesn't occur.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/wrap_fwo.pl?IDQ60359.html"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {

            // Code that passes my web service data into an NSArray list

            // self->sensors = locations;
            self->sensors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key4",@"key5",@"key6",nil];

            NSLog(@"Try to reload the tableView");
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];

    self->sensors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1",@"key2",@"key3",nil];

}
```

My app starts, and shows key1, key2 and key3 in the `UITableView` list. Key4, key5, key6 never show. The code in the completionHandler does run, I've verified it by NSLogging the way I create my array to put into the `UITableView`.

"Try to reload the tableView" is displayed in the console. However some NSLogs I've added to my `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` functions are not shown after "try to reload the tableView".

How can I get my code to update the `UITableView` to show key4, key5, key6?

Comment: Make sure sensor is mutable.

Comment: does it print `Try to reload the tableView` on the console ?

Comment: It wasn't, I've now changed it. However I also note that after I call reloadData, the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath functions are never called.

Comment: Yes "Try to reload the tableView" is displayed. NSLogs in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath are not displayed after "try to load the tableView".

Comment: call the reload data in the main thread.

Comment: Make sure  1) you update or reload Tableview on main thread only, 2) tableview have connection with the datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my problem wasn't about the thread. The code in the question works, once I added this referencing outlet:

[image: In the storyboard]

Control dragging from the UITableView in storyboard to the ViewController Interface added this line:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

I had previously manually put this in but that didn't add the Referencing Outlet in the storyboard. I forgot this step. Once this step was done, I didn't have to worry about what thread I was calling UITableView reloadData from.

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading tableview on main thread

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self->sensors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"key1",@"key2",@"key3",nil];  

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/wrap_fwo.pl?IDQ60359.html"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {

            // Code that passes my web service data into an NSArray list

            // self->sensors = locations;
            NSArray *newObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key4",@"key5",@"key6",nil];

            [self->sensors addObjectsFromArray:newObjects];


            NSLog(@"Try to reload the tableView");
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];


}
```

Comment: I've just tried that, including setting up the self->sensors array inside the dispatch_async block and no change. The UITableView never tries to reload.

Comment: check whether the tableview datasource is binded properly.  self->sensors should append the new keys from API if you want to add the new keys to existing array , so make the Array a NSMutableArray. Try keeping a breakpoint on NumberOfrows tableview method and check whether it is called or not ?

Comment: Turned out this was the issue, not the thread. I didn't have the Referencing Outlet there.